# How do I place read more - read less button always at the end of the paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a read more / read less button on my homepage, now everything is working fine I just want to make read more button always at the end of the paragraph. So when its read more **(closed)** it will stick right after the end of the first paragraph and when its read less **(opened)** it also needs to be on the right of the second paragraph.

**This is how it currenty looks:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a34Fq.jpg)

**This is how I want it to be:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klRuR.jpg)

**Here is the code snippet:**

```js
$(function(){
 $.fn.readmore = function( options ) {

  var settings = $.extend({
   div: this,
   hideText: "Read Less...",
   readText: "Read More...",
   isTextShown: false,
   effect: true,
   effectOption: "fast",
   buttonClasses: "btn-primary opacity-rollover",
   id: "read-more-action"
  },options);

  if(settings.isTextShown === false){
   $(settings.div).hide();
   $(settings.div).parent().append("<button id='"+settings.id+"' class='"+ settings.buttonClasses +"'>"+ settings.readText + "</button>");
  }else{
   $(settings.div).parent().append("<button id='"+settings.id+"' class='"+ settings.buttonClasses +"'>"+ settings.hideText + "</button>");
  }

  $(settings.div).parent().find("#" + settings.id).bind("click.readmore", function () {
   if(settings.isTextShown === false){
    $(settings.div).parent().find("#" + settings.id).text(settings.hideText);
    if(settings.effect === true){
     $(settings.div).fadeIn(settings.effectOption);
    }else{
     $(settings.div).show();
    }
    settings.isTextShown = true;
   }else{
    $(settings.div).parent().find("#" + settings.id).text(settings.readText);
    if(settings.effect === true){
     $(settings.div).hide();
    }else{
     $(settings.div).fadeOut(settings.effectOption);
    }
    settings.isTextShown = false;
   }
  });

 };
});

  $(function(){
   $(".read-more").readmore({
    buttonClasses: "btn btn-primary",
   });
  });
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.1.1/materia/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 2em">
 <h1>Read More/Read Less Buttons</h1>
  <article>
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas dictum metus ac semper finibus. Praesent vulputate augue ac tempus congue.
    Curabitur in sapien semper, tristique arcu eget, pharetra risus. Donec tempus aliquet purus eu lobortis.
    Etiam ac finibus felis. Integer congue sit amet neque sit amet pellentesque. Donec cursus interdum rutrum.
    Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
   </p>
   <p class="read-more">Praesent luctus at erat at sagittis.
    Etiam posuere, erat nec laoreet ornare, odio dui mattis nisl, convallis semper ligula lectus eu turpis.
    Phasellus pharetra risus tortor, eget fringilla tortor laoreet at. Quisque egestas tristique dui. Mauris non iaculis ex.
    Ut pellentesque, massa ut molestie egestas, tortor leo imperdiet sem, vitae malesuada nibh dolor in magna. Etiam pulvinar pharetra dolor, vel dapibus ipsum commodo eget.
    Praesent turpis odio, suscipit ut ullamcorper vel, finibus at ligula. Phasellus dolor lectus, molestie a velit sed, iaculis rhoncus risus.
    Ut id pellentesque erat, quis elementum ligula. Donec dignissim diam sem, a bibendum erat mattis quis. Vivamus id erat dui. Vestibulum sollicitudin ac justo at lacinia.
   </p>
  </article>
 </div>
```

Any help is appriciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your

elements

```
display: inline
```

```js
$(function(){
 $.fn.readmore = function( options ) {

  var settings = $.extend({
   div: this,
   hideText: "Read Less...",
   readText: "Read More...",
   isTextShown: false,
   effect: true,
   effectOption: "fast",
   buttonClasses: "btn-primary opacity-rollover",
   id: "read-more-action"
  },options);

  if(settings.isTextShown === false){
   $(settings.div).hide();
   $(settings.div).parent().append("<button id='"+settings.id+"' class='"+ settings.buttonClasses +"'>"+ settings.readText + "</button>");
  }else{
   $(settings.div).parent().append("<button id='"+settings.id+"' class='"+ settings.buttonClasses +"'>"+ settings.hideText + "</button>");
  }

  $(settings.div).parent().find("#" + settings.id).bind("click.readmore", function () {
   if(settings.isTextShown === false){
    $(settings.div).parent().find("#" + settings.id).text(settings.hideText);
    if(settings.effect === true){
     $(settings.div).fadeIn(settings.effectOption);
    }else{
     $(settings.div).show();
    }
    settings.isTextShown = true;
   }else{
    $(settings.div).parent().find("#" + settings.id).text(settings.readText);
    if(settings.effect === true){
     $(settings.div).hide();
    }else{
     $(settings.div).fadeOut(settings.effectOption);
    }
    settings.isTextShown = false;
   }
  });

 };
});

  $(function(){
   $(".read-more").readmore({
    buttonClasses: "btn btn-primary",
   });
  });
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.1.1/materia/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 2em">
 <h1>Read More/Read Less Buttons</h1>
  <article>
   <p style="display: inline">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas dictum metus ac semper finibus. Praesent vulputate augue ac tempus congue.
    Curabitur in sapien semper, tristique arcu eget, pharetra risus. Donec tempus aliquet purus eu lobortis.
    Etiam ac finibus felis. Integer congue sit amet neque sit amet pellentesque. Donec cursus interdum rutrum.
    Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
   </p>
   <p class="read-more" style="display: inline">Praesent luctus at erat at sagittis.
    Etiam posuere, erat nec laoreet ornare, odio dui mattis nisl, convallis semper ligula lectus eu turpis.
    Phasellus pharetra risus tortor, eget fringilla tortor laoreet at. Quisque egestas tristique dui. Mauris non iaculis ex.
    Ut pellentesque, massa ut molestie egestas, tortor leo imperdiet sem, vitae malesuada nibh dolor in magna. Etiam pulvinar pharetra dolor, vel dapibus ipsum commodo eget.
    Praesent turpis odio, suscipit ut ullamcorper vel, finibus at ligula. Phasellus dolor lectus, molestie a velit sed, iaculis rhoncus risus.
    Ut id pellentesque erat, quis elementum ligula. Donec dignissim diam sem, a bibendum erat mattis quis. Vivamus id erat dui. Vestibulum sollicitudin ac justo at lacinia.
   </p>
  </article>
 </div>
```

Comment: this is good but now the text is together and I want it seperate, also when I add padding to it the button goes away. How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: Regarding the text being separate you can make through jquery the first <p> display: block when you click "Read more" and display: inline when you click "Read less". About the padding not sure what is going on without a snippet :)